# Temporarily create image url out of a blob object

Tags: reactjs, antd

I want users to see an image preview on a background like this. But when I accessed the thumb URL, it was low quality and distorted. Another user suggested accessing the image URL out of a blob object.

As I'm new to programming, I don't understand how to access the blob object and achieve this.

[image]

I'm using ant design.

This is how I'm uploading the file. I did a console.log of(fileList), I got the below screenshot as output.

```
const [fileList, setFileList] = useState([]);
          
  const onChange = ({ fileList: newFileList }) => {
      console.log(fileList)
      setFileList(()=>(newFileList));
    };            


return (

<div>
          <UploadButton  
          fileList={fileList}
          beforeUpload={() => false}
          onChange={onChange}
           aspect={2} listType="picture" />

<div/>
)
```

Really appreciate any sort of help. I have put a lot of time on this already.

[image]

Comment: Why are you passing the anonymous function `() => (newFileList)` to `setFileList` instead `setFileList(newFileList)` ?

Comment: Good catch. It's a mistake on my side.